# Extracting Structure Failed when importing an sbt project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to setup Scala on IntelliJ IDE and when I create a new project it seems fine. When I import another project it errors: `Extracting Structure Failed`.

The sbt shell seems to be working. What can be the issue?

This is my `build.sbt`:

```
course := "progfun1"
assignment := "example"
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-language:implicitConversions", "-deprecation")
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test 
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a", "-v", "-s")
```

Here is the log:

```
2020-10-17 16:45:29,222 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,291 [     69]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-202.7660.26, 06 Oct 2020 11:32) 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,292 [     70]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,292 [     70]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 (JetBrains s.r.o.) 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,293 [     71]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,294 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms128m -Xmx1776m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\Melih\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\jbr\\bin;D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\jbr\\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2020.2 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\Melih\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\Melih\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,294 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\jbr\\bin;D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\jbr\\bin\server 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,294 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\jbr\bin 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,296 [     74]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_US JNU=Cp1254 file.encoding=Cp1254
  idea.config.path=C:\Users\Melih\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2
  idea.system.path=C:\Users\Melih\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2
  idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\Melih\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\plugins
  idea.log.path=C:\Users\Melih\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\log 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,552 [    330]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 255 ms 
2020-10-17 16:45:29,865 [    643]   INFO - ntellij.idea.ApplicationLoader - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@10bac343[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@6f4f8382 
2020-10-17 16:45:30,067 [    845]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2020-10-17 16:45:30,371 [   1149]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\Groovy, version=202.7660.26) misses optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /META-INF/duplicates-groovy.xml
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newInputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:591)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newInputStream(ZipPath.java:721)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newInputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:275)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.BasePathResolver.resolvePath(BasePathResolver.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginXmlPathResolver.resolvePath(PluginXmlPathResolver.java:58)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.XmlReader.readDependencies(XmlReader.java:215)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.readExternal(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromJar(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromDirAndNormalize(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:145)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromFileOrDir(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:120)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.lambda$loadDescriptorsFromDir$1(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-10-17 16:45:30,373 [   1151]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\Groovy, version=202.7660.26) misses optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /META-INF/duplicates-detection-groovy.xml
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newInputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:591)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newInputStream(ZipPath.java:721)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newInputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:275)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.BasePathResolver.resolvePath(BasePathResolver.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginXmlPathResolver.resolvePath(PluginXmlPathResolver.java:58)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.XmlReader.readDependencies(XmlReader.java:215)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.readExternal(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromJar(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromDirAndNormalize(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:145)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromFileOrDir(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:120)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.lambda$loadDescriptorsFromDir$1(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-10-17 16:45:30,523 [   1301]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Java, id=com.intellij.java, path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\java, version=202.7660.26) misses optional descriptor profiler-java.xml 
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /META-INF/profiler-java.xml
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newInputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:591)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newInputStream(ZipPath.java:721)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newInputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:275)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.BasePathResolver.resolvePath(BasePathResolver.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginXmlPathResolver.resolvePath(PluginXmlPathResolver.java:58)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.XmlReader.readDependencies(XmlReader.java:215)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.readExternal(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromJar(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromDirAndNormalize(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:145)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromFileOrDir(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:120)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.lambda$loadDescriptorsFromDir$1(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-10-17 16:45:30,603 [   1381]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: IDEA CORE (202.7660.26), com.intellij.platform.images (202.7660.26), JetBrains maven model api classes (202.7660.26), JetBrains Repository Search (202.7660.26), Subversion (202.7660.26), XPathView + XSLT (202.7660.26), XSLT Debugger (202.7660.26), Smali Support (202.7660.26), Configuration Script (202.7660.26), Copyright (202.7660.26), Gradle (202.7660.26), Java (202.7660.26), Bytecode Viewer (202.7660.26), JUnit (202.7660.26), Java IDE Customization (202.7660.26), Java Stream Debugger (202.7660.26), Eclipse Interoperability (202.7660.26), Java Bytecode Decompiler (202.7660.26), Windows 10 Light Theme (202.7660.26), Properties (202.7660.26), Ant (202.7660.26), Java Internationalization (202.7660.26), UI Designer (202.7660.26), JavaFX (202.7660.26), Resource Bundle Editor (202.7660.26), Machine Learning Code Completion (202.7660.26), Task Management (202.7660.26), Mercurial (202.7660.26), Webp Support (202.7660.26), EditorConfig (202.7660.26), Terminal (202.7660.26), Git (202.7660.26), ChangeReminder (202.7660.26), Next File Prediction (202.7660.26), GitHub (202.7660.26), Shell Script (202.7660.26), TextMate Bundles (202.7660.26), YAML (202.7660.26), Settings Repository (202.7660.26), IntelliLang (202.7660.26), TestNG (202.7660.26), Code Coverage for Java (202.7660.26), Groovy (202.7660.26), Maven (202.7660.26), Gradle-Java (202.7660.26), Plugin DevKit (202.7660.26), Gradle-Maven (202.7660.26), Kotlin (1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-6), Android (10.4.0.202.7660.26), Markdown (202.7660.26), Grazie (202.7660.26) 
2020-10-17 16:45:30,603 [   1381]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Scala (2020.2.27) 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,089 [   1867]   INFO - m.intellij.util.io.StorageLock - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1696 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,108 [   1886]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - un-interruptible FileChannel-s will be used for indexes 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,307 [   2085]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63343 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,319 [   2097]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,332 [   2110]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,455 [   2233]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,741 [   2519]   INFO - BridgeProjectLifecycleListener - Using legacy project model to open project 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,849 [   2627]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2020-10-17 16:45:31,946 [   2724]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2020-10-17 16:45:32,654 [   3432]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Loading Project code style 
2020-10-17 16:45:32,681 [   3459]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Project code style loaded 
2020-10-17 16:45:33,004 [   3782]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation) 
2020-10-17 16:45:33,716 [   4494]   INFO - leBasedIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 2408 
2020-10-17 16:45:33,993 [   4771]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 276 
2020-10-17 16:45:34,205 [   4983]   WARN - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activities registered via registerPostStartupActivity must be dumb-aware: org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.lang.psi.impl.toplevel.synthetic.SyntheticClassesListener$$Lambda$1296/0x0000000100f64440@1eb6449d 
2020-10-17 16:45:34,248 [   5026]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2020-10-17 16:45:34,308 [   5086]   INFO - .CodeStyleSettingsInferService - settings inference skipped: already done 
2020-10-17 16:45:34,320 [   5098]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'compiler.process.jdk' has changed to '' 
2020-10-17 16:45:34,349 [   5127]   WARN - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activities registered via registerPostStartupActivity must be dumb-aware: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.ui.KotlinConfigurationCheckerComponent$projectOpened$1@2764562c 
2020-10-17 16:45:34,843 [   5621]   INFO - penapi.application.Experiments - Experimental features enabled for user: wsl.p9.support, wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser, inline.browse.button, linux.native.menu, recent.and.edited.files.together, show.create.new.element.in.popup, copy.reference.popup, new.large.text.file.viewer, property.value.inplace.editing, terminal.shell.command.handling, scala.uast.enabled 
2020-10-17 16:45:36,312 [   7090]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 105 millis (read time: 88) 
2020-10-17 16:45:36,638 [   7416]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2020-10-17 16:45:36,720 [   7498]   INFO - ation.SbtCompilationSupervisor - Listening to incoming sbt compilation events on port 0. 
2020-10-17 16:45:36,733 [   7511]   INFO - ProjectRootPostStartUpActivity - C:/Users/Melih/Desktop/example/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2020-10-17 16:45:36,795 [   7573]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 840ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:45:37,553 [   8331]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 5917 ms 
2020-10-17 16:45:37,722 [   8500]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 123ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:45:37,864 [   8642]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [C:/Users/Melih/Desktop/example] resolution task started 
2020-10-17 16:45:39,187 [   9965]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2020-10-17 16:45:46,515 [  17293]   INFO - gnostic.WindowsDefenderChecker - Windows Defender status: Failed to get excluded patterns 
2020-10-17 16:45:55,228 [  26006]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [C:/Users/Melih/Desktop/example] resolution task executed in 17364 ms. 
2020-10-17 16:45:55,796 [  26574]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 58 ms 
2020-10-17 16:45:55,950 [  26728]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage 
2020-10-17 16:45:55,978 [  26756]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=example, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Melih\Desktop\example)CommitMessageInspectionProfile took 29 ms 
2020-10-17 16:45:58,027 [  28805]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 20303ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:45:58,036 [  28814]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index 
2020-10-17 16:45:58,052 [  28830]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2020-10-17 16:45:58,660 [  29438]   INFO - .ScalaCompilerReferenceService - Initialized ScalaCompilerReferenceService in example, current compiler mode = JPS 
2020-10-17 16:45:59,967 [  30745]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Searching for external libraries with Android resources. Found 0 libraries. took 13ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:45:59,967 [  30745]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Searching for external libraries with Android resources. Found 0 libraries. took 3ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:45:59,967 [  30745]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Searching for external libraries with Android resources. Found 0 libraries. took 13ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:45:59,967 [  30745]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Searching for external libraries with Android resources. Found 0 libraries. took 13ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-10-17 16:49:40,869 [ 251647]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [C:/Users/Melih/Desktop/example] resolution task started 
2020-10-17 16:49:47,002 [ 257780]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=example, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Melih\Desktop\example)KotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 17 ms, ScalaProjectSettings took 13 ms 
2020-10-17 16:49:54,667 [ 265445]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [C:/Users/Melih/Desktop/example] resolution task executed in 13798 ms. 
2020-10-17 16:49:55,129 [ 265907]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 72 ms 
2020-10-17 16:49:55,205 [ 265983]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=example, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Melih\Desktop\example)JsonSchemaMappingsProjectConfiguration took 49 ms 
2020-10-17 16:50:07,409 [ 278187]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
```

Comment: Are yous sure that this is your build.sbt? `course` is not a valid word. This is not the progfun's sbt: https://github.com/iluu/scala-progfun/blob/master/example/build.sbt

Comment: Can you try to reinstall and install intellij?

Comment: did that as well

Comment: yep thank you regardless but nothing works

Answer (score 2):

Check the Java version, I resolved the same issue by downgrading the java version from 18 to 1.8
Spark 2.4.7, scala 2.11, and Java 1.8 will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find some deps, let me show you

```
name := "neo4j-spark-scala-j8"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.13"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.0", //ok
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "4.2.3", // ok
  // "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "4.0.0" // it doesn't work
)
```

if I de-comment the last dep, I will get your same error

Comment: @Melih Have you tried this approach to debugging? It seems likely that this is the problem.

Comment: What was the specific issue in your case? The dependency was not downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before, when I installed `SBT EXECUTOR` plugin, every thing worked fine.

I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while importing Spark dependencies. It worked well when I donwgraded my scalaVersion from 2.13 to 2.10.
Please try downgrading your scalaVersion to some lower version. It can work at you as well.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.